# Is it possible to use OpenGL ES on iOS through RubyMotion?

Tags: ios, ruby, opengl-es, rubymotion

I know [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/) is relatively new, but I'd like to find out if it's possible/easy to use OpenGL ES with it before I buy a license to make an iOS game I've been planning for a while.

The reason I'm wondering is that I understand RubyMotion wraps all the Cocoa/Objective-C stuff but OpenGL on iOS is a set of C functions (glBegin(), glEnd(), etc.)

If anyone that purchased RubyMotion could help me out in finding out or point me to a piece of documentation, I'd be extremely grateful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. The [official site](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/) says so.

> #### Interfacing with C
>
> You do not need to be a C programmer in order to use RubyMotion, however some basic notions, explained in this section, will be required.
>   Objective-C is a superset of the C language. Objective-C methods can therefore accept and return C types.
>   Also, while Objective-C is the main programming language used in the iOS SDK, some frameworks are only available in C APIs.
>   RubyMotion comes with an interface that allows Ruby to deal with the C part of APIs.

Comment: Didn't stumble onto that part of the site by myself.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I have used CoreImage/Quartz with RubyMotion in this sample app: https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/Trollify

So yes, C APIs work just fine and I'm sure that includes OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

They have a working demo in the RubyMotionSample project https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/HelloGL

Comment: It just lacks some comments for non OpenGL users =).